# ReactJS adding a value to Form.submit() on Menu click

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd, web-frontend

fellow Stackers! I probably have a simple question, but can't seem to find the answer...

**What I want to achieve:**

[image]

I have this kind of commenting logic. Basically, when a person comments without any status change a button calls *postComment* and all works fine. Now when a user comments & selects to change status it presses on *Menu.Item* (ref [antd](https://ant.design/components/button/#header)) which would send the element key for me to grab and work around some logic.

```
const onMenuClick = (e) => {
    postComment(e);
};

<Menu onClick={onMenuClick}>
        <Menu.Item key="Done">
            <div>
                <Row>
                    <Col md={2}>
                        <CheckCircleOutlined style={{ color: "limegreen", fontSize: '1.5em' }} className='mt-2 mr-2' />
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={20} className="ml-2">
                        <Row md={24}><Col className="font-weight-semibold"> Comment & Done</Col></Row>
                        <Row md={24}><Col className="text-muted">Comment & calculation status is done.</Col></Row>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </div>
        </Menu.Item>
```

Above code does work, but for certain reasons *(or my lack of knowledge)* but It will jump over the usual HTML submit rules and now the function will only check for validation inside.

So what do I want? I want to use the Menu something like this:

```
   <Menu onClick={(e) => formComment.submit(e)}>
```

This would submit a form and pass the Menu.Item key which I could use.

My postComment function:

```
    const postComment = async (e) => {

        console.log(e);

        setCommentsLoading(true)
        const formData = new FormData();
        const { id } = props.match.params;
        let comment;

        

       formComment.validateFields().then(async (values) => {

        
        //Upload and set Documents for post. This fires before validation, which is not ideal.
        if (fileList.length > 0) {
            fileList.forEach(file => {
                formData.append('files', file);
            });
            
            await commentService.upload(formData).then((res) => { //Await only works after Async, so cant put it below validateFields()
                res.data.forEach((element) => {
                    documents.push(element.id);
                    setDocuments(documents)
                });
            }).catch(error => {
                message.error(error);
            }).finally(() => {
                setDocuments(documents)
            }
            )
        } //This basically uploads and then does everything else.
            console.log(values.comment)
            //Checks if status should be changed.
            if (e.key !== undefined) {
                let variable = commentsVariable + 'Status';

                let put = {
                    [variable]: e.key,
                };

                if (fileList.length <= 0 && e.key === "Done") {
                    message.error('Should have attachments.')
                    mainService.get(id).then(res => {
                    })
                    setCommentsLoading(false)
                    return
                } else {
                    //No idea how to update status in the view.js, needs some sort of a trigger/callback.
                    mainService.put(put, id).then(res => { }) 
                        .catch(err => {
                            console.log(err)
                            return
                        })
                }
            }

                if(values.comment === undefined) {
                    comment = `This was aut-generated comment.`;
                } else {
                    comment = values.comment;
                }

                let post = {
                    comment: comment,
                    [commentsVariable]: id,
                    attachments: documents,
                    user: random(1, 4),
                };

                commentService.post(post).then((res) => {
                    mainService.get(id).then(res => {
                        setComments(res.data.data.attributes.comments.data)
                        message.success('Comment successfully posted!')

                        formComment.resetFields()
                        setFileList([])
                        setDocuments([])
                    })
                });

            }).catch(error => {
                error.errorFields.forEach(item => {
                    message.error(item.errors)
                    setFileList([])
                    setDocuments([])
                })
            })

    setCommentsLoading(false);
};
```

My form looks like this (I won't include Form.Items).

```
<Form
    name="commentForm"
    layout={"vertical"}
    form={formComment}
    onFinish={(e) => postComment(e)}
    className="ant-advanced-search-form">
```

So in the end, I just want a proper HTML rule check before the function fires, no matter if I press the "Comment" button or press the ones with the status update.

Answer (score 0):

So I kind of worked around it. Basically I just added a hidden field:

```
<Form.Item name="key" className={"mb-1"} hidden>
 <Input/>
</Form.Item>
```

Then on Menu i addeda function that has onClick trigger, which sets the value to whatever key is there and submits:

```
const onMenuClick = (e) => {
console.log(e.key)
formComment.setFieldsValue({
    key: String(e.key)
})
formComment.submit()
};
```

I'm pretty sure this is a dirty workaround, but hey, it works for a Junior dev :D Either way, I'll try to test it without hidden field where it just adds a new value.